# Filter data over a period of time in Fabric.io

Tags: ios, dashboard, fabric.io

I have been using **Fabric.io** on my iOS app for 2 months. It's an e-commerce app so I'm using custom events for monitoring *Product search* and *Purchases*. What I noticed it's that though the tables in **"Answers"** get filled up with data it's not possible to define the date range of the reported query of searching for older events. The dashboard panels look limited to the latest data with no possibilities of customisation.

Is there any way to perform a proper filtering?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: still nothing,I'm sorry..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently the dashboard only allows you to see the data from the most recent 30 days. If you use the export function you get the data from one year.

They know that some people want to have it, but I don't think they are working on that.

Would be great if everyone could add their +1 on this question:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-answers-how-to-select-date-range/58599

Hope this helps.